# ¿Cómo guardar datos como porcentaje? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Estoy generando un modelo en el que quiero guardar 3 datos como porcentajes para después aplicarlos en unas fórmulas.

### Modelo

```
class Factura(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
    n_factura = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField() #fecha en la que empieza la factura
    fecha_fin = models.DateField() #fecha en la que termina la factura
    comision = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    iva = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    rte_iva = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    rte_ica = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    rte_fte = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    porcentaje_rte_iva = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    porcentaje_rte_ica = models.IntegerField()
    porcentaje_rte_fte = models.IntegerField()
    porcentaje_comision = models.IntegerField()
    porcentaje_iva = models.IntegerField()
```

Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de guardar datos como  porcentajes y que sean númericos o de alguna manera hacer una fórmula tipo:

```
porcentaje_iva = %15
calculo_iva = total_producto * porcentaje_iva
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te dejo aquí una forma de hacerlo, la cosa es poner el producto como decimal de 0.15 en caso de ser el 15% y después sumar `Precio + (Precio * PorcentajeDeIva)`

```
Iva=0.15  #Iva = 15% dividido entre 100. 
PrecioProducto= 25  
ProductoConIva= PrecioProducto + (PrecioProducto*Iva)

print "Precio con IVA incluido =", ProductoConIva
```

De esta manera tienes una forma de sumar un porcentaje a un precio, puedes variarlo como quieras, sumando, restando. Ya como tú veas.

En cambio, si lo que quieres es guardar `15%` como `iva = 15` la cosa cambia a:

```
Iva=float(15)  #Iva = 15%  decimal.
PrecioProducto= 25
ProductoConIva=PrecioProducto + (PrecioProducto*(Iva/100))

print "Precio con IVA incluido =", ProductoConIva
```

Comment: Pero de la misma forma tambien quiero mostrarlo en el template que se está aplicando ese IVA. Ahora mismo lo que hago es guardarlo como entero y aplicarle esta formula: `(precio_producto * iva)/100`. Al final sería lo mismo.

Comment: Dame un momento y edito la respuesta para lo que dices.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si es un dato que se puede calcular con los que ya tienes recomendaría no almacenarlo y simplemente definir en el modelo una funcion porcentaje decorada como **property** el problema principal de almacenar un dato calculado es en caso de actualizarse sus parametros se tiene que recalcular siempre y si se pasa puede inducir a error

```
class Factura(models.Model):
     id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True) 
     ...

     @property
     def porcentaje(self):
         pass #calcular porcentaje


f = Factura.objects.get(id=31212) #al alzar esto
print(f.porcentaje)
```